# Dynamically insert rows based on first row and last row parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to dynamically insert a certain number of rows into my database based on a first row parameter and a last row parameter. Here's what I've tried and it ended up inserting 49,000 rows into my database - all with the same values - `MyName-10`.

```
@NamePrefix nvarchar(25)
, @FirstRow int -- Begin with this number  (10)
, @LastRow int --End with this number (15)

AS
BEGIN
  IF @LastRow IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int = @FirstRow
    WHILE (@i <= @LastRow)
      INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
        VALUES (@NamePrefix + Cast(@i AS varchar))
    SET @i = @i + 1;
  END
END
```

My table results should look like:

```
Name:
MyName-10
MyName-11
MyName-12
MyName-13
MyName-14
MyName-15
```

Comment: Your code failed you because you created an endless loop. You didn't use a BEGIN/END block inside your while loop so only the first row executes and the line to increment @i never fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend:

```
WHILE (@i <= @LastRow)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
    VALUES (@NamePrefix + Cast(@i AS varchar(255)));
  SET @i = @i + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why would my procedure have inserted 49,000 rows? Did the operation time out? Thankfully, it didn't happen, but why didn't this keep going until the server ran out of space?

Comment: @Shane . . . The question is why it ran more than once.  That I don't know.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because in their original code they didn't have BEGIN/END inside the loop. It was an endless loop which I can only assume they stopped running after it ran for 49,000 inserts.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this with a cursor in the first place? This is nothing but a single insert statement if you use a tally table instead.

I keep a tally table as a view on my system but you can do this inline with a couple ctes or whatever. Here is the code for my tally table.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now for the inserts you are trying to do this becomes painless, instant and loopless.

```
declare @NamePrefix nvarchar(25) = 'MyName-'
    , @FirstRow int = 10 -- Begin with this number  (10)
    , @LastRow int = 15 --End with this number (15)

INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
select @NamePrefix + Cast(t.N AS varchar(10))
from cteTally t
where t.N >= @FirstRow
    and t.N <= @LastRow
```